# how to get the list of users from keycloak by using httppost/rest-api

Tags: http-post, keycloak-services

I am new to **keycloak** any help will be appreciable.
I'm able to get the list of user details by using the keycloak api, I want to know how we can get it by using http-post.

```
Keycloak kc = Keycloak.getInstance("url-path", "realm", "username", "password", "admin-cli");
```

By using this keycloak object I am able to get the list of users. But when I want to get the list of users by using http-post or rest api call by using the end point url which is given by keycloak I am not able to get the access token based on token I am getting only the particular user , I want list of users by using rest api's.

Comment: by using that keycloak object i'm able to get the list of users.

Comment: but i want to know how we get the list of user and session detalis by using http-post or rest api of keycloak.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [Offical Keycloak Admin REST API Docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource) (Scroll down a bit to the **Get users Returns a list of users, filtered according to query parameters** section), you will find that there are 2 query parameters available: `first` and `max`.

If you set `first` as 10 and `max` as 15, then first 10 users will be skipped, and you will receive the next 15 *i.e. users 11 to 25* in response.

Use the following request:

```
GET https://$KEYCLOAK_HOST/auth/admin/$REALM/users?first=10&max=15
```

P.S. - Don't forget the Authorization Header.

Comment: Updated url  auth/admin/realms/<realm>/users

Comment: Is the total records count value still returned? I cannot find it on v20.0.2

Comment: The response structure did not work when I opened the docs. Looks like they have moved the Total count to a separate endpoint entirely: "Returns the number of users that match the given criteria."

Answer (score 4):

Below are the steps to achieve this by key-cloak rest-api first create the url

```
String fetchAllUsers = URL+"/admin/realms/"+realmName+"/users?";
```

Now if you have millions of users you don't want to do fetch all user in one go so keycloak support rest-api with pagination,in your rest post query you can ask
`tenantName`,`queryString`,`Limit`,`PageNumber`

```
fetchAllUsers(String tenantName, List<String> queryString, String limit, String pageNumber)
```

now these thing will help to create a query which will send only that many record which will not impact performance of keycloak as well as web-api.

In `queryString` user can pass the filter criteria like if he want to search by name,lastname,email-id or user want result in ascending or descending order.That you have to parse and create a query String so it will resemble to the rest query of keycloak. After doing that you can concatenate the query String with  `fetchAllUsers` .

Your query will be like this

```
https://<IP ADDRESS>/<PORT>/admin/realms/<REALM NAME>/users?q=username=<USER NAME>ASC&email=<EMAIL ID>&limit=<RECORD LIMIT>&page=<PAGE NO>
```

Please ignore typo if you found anything.

Comment: I don't think this will work since if you look at keycloak rest admin api which is https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html then under the `GET /{realm}/users` endpoint details there are only `first` and `max` query parameters available. Did you verify this query working or not?

Comment: Check https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-community/blob/master/design/rest-api-guideline.md#pagination

Comment: Hi, @Subodh do you know how to get many users by a list of ids?

Comment: @cYee I think Ids are secure ,but you can check the official rest-api documentation .

Comment: I did, but it seems there is no way to get it from admin api, just try my luck in SO.

Answer (score 0):

According with official documentation :)

```
POST /{realm}/users 
mean
POST {{keycloak_url}}/admin/realms/{{keycloak_realm}}/users

Ex. POST https://mykeycloak/admin/realms/myrealm/users
```